# jq: How to Catenate an Array and Strip Spaces

Tags: concatenation, trim, jq, strip

The following `jq` command (Windows) successfully catenates all the "text" properties into one string replacing any spaces with a single space albeit in a roundabout way. Almost correct. What I really want is to first replace any leading or trailing space in "text", then catenate all "text" properties. A difference being that embedded (non-leading, non-trailing) spaces must not be removed. How can this be done?

```
jq ".segments[].words | map(.text?) | join(\",\") | gsub(\"[ ]\"; \"\") | gsub(\"[,]\"; \" \")"
```

Comment: It's "concatenate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
def trim: sub("^ *";"") | sub(" *$";"");
```

Or you could simply use: gsub("^\s|\s*$";"")

There are other ways to trim a string but the above should get you started.

Comment: Indeed it got me started. Thank you. I combined initial and trailing matches into one `gsub` followed by a `join` of properties into a single string. The join inserted a single space while joining. The Windows escaping is ugly. `jq ".segments[].words | map(.text? | gsub(\"(^\\s^|\\s$)\";\"\")) | join(\" \")"`

Comment: Using a variation of your `def`: `jq "def trim: gsub(\"(^\\s^|\\s$)\";\"\"); .segments[].words | map(.text? | trim ) | join(\" \")"` Wow, I feel like a `jq` grownup now. Thanks again.

Comment: To avoid the escaping ugliness, I'd recommend using the -f FILENAME command-line option. Consider also the startup file (~/.jq).

Comment: The second ^ in your gsub expression does not look right.

Comment: That must be a Windows thing. In any case, please note that the gsub expression with \\s$ will only strip one space codepoint from the end of the input string.